# discord.js v13.1.0 roles is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to add a specific role to a member on a guild and the docs for this version of discord.js says its with ".roles.add", but when I use ".roles" return undefined, so I cant work with undefined. Anyone knows how to set a role in this version of discord.js?

Code:

```
const member = guild.members.fetch(result.DISCORD);
if(member) {
  let role = guild.roles.fetch('879811123283644490')
  member.roles.add(role)
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\index.js:54:22
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\index.js:46:13)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Thales bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Guild.members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves with a Collection of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s.

Thus, in your code, you are attempting to call `Promise.roles.add()`, which is why you get the error.

To fix the error, you need to `await` the promise (make sure the function is `async`) or use `.then()`:

Using `async`/`await`:

```js
const member = await guild.members.fetch(result.DISCORD);
if(member) {
  const role = await guild.roles.fetch('879811123283644490');
  member.roles.add(role);
```

Using `.then()`:

```js
guild.members.fetch(result.DISCORD).then(member => {
  return guild.roles.fetch('879811123283644490');
}).then(role => {
  return member.roles.add(role);
}).catch((err) => {
  // handle errors
});
```